# installing opencv for python issues

Tags: python, macos, installation, opencv

I'm running OS X Leopard.  I followed [this site](http://thepetitegeek.blogspot.com/2009/09/installing-opencv-on-mac-os-x-with.html) to install it.  Trying to run any demo script, I now get "No module named opencv.cv", which is obviously stopping me from doing any programming.  I am running python 2.5.1 (yes, I know it's kind of old).

Why would this be, and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Pay attention that at least once for me, the installer installed the python module to the wrong site-dir, where python was unable to find it. Double check that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile openCV unfortunately.  It's not that hard to do though at least.

Answer (score 0):

A nice route is to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org): First, be sure to have `py26-numpy` installed to have support for basic functions such as `cv.fromarray` :

```
sudo port install py26-numpy
```

Then, `opencv` will compile (with no problem on my side):

```
sudo port install opencv +python26
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link tells to install OpenCV with MacPorts, which currently installs version 2.2.0. The API was changed for 2.2, so that might be the reason `opencv.cv` doesn't exist (also your link is written for the ancient 1.0). OpenCV changelog explains it:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV%20Change%20Logs

It isn't clear to me how up-to-date the OpenCV documentation is nowadays but I recommend looking at it:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html

(Python examples there begin with `import cv`)